# How to change color of background again without reloading?

Tags: javascript, html, css, button

I am trying to make a website which changes its color when a button is pressed. For that, I created an array with colors and got a random colour using `Math.floor`. I then used `onclick()` to change the colour but there is a problem. The color is getting changed but when I press the button again, nothing is happening and to change the colour again, I have to reload the page. I tried using `e.preventDefault` in my onclick function but still it isn't working.

```js
let arr = ["black", "red", "silver", "gray", "white", "maroon", "red", "purple", "fuchsia", "green", "lime", "olive", "yellow", "navy", "blue", "teal", "aqua"]
let item = arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)];

console.log(item)

document.getElementById('btn').onclick = function(e) {
  document.body.style.background = item
  document.getElementById('name').innerHTML = item
  e.preventDefault()
}
```

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

#btn {
  border: 3px solid green;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 50px;
}

#name {
  border: 3px solid green;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="name">Colour name will appear here</div>
<button id="btn" type="button">Click Me for colour change in background</button>
<script src="script.js"></script>
<script src="https://replit.com/public/js/replit-badge-v2.js" theme="dark" position="bottom-right"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can put `let item = arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)]` into the onclick function. You need to reload the page because the item variable only load the value once. If you put into the function, you will load a new value and get new color.

```
document.getElementById('btn').onclick = function(e) {
let item = arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)];

  document.body.style.background = item
  document.getElementById('name').innerHTML = item
  e.preventDefault()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you are only setting item (i.e. the colour to change to) once, so the button only ever changes the colour to this one. This is why you think its doing nothing

Answer (score 0):

Declare the variable outside of the onclick function and on every click assign the new value to the item variable

Answer (score 0):

You just have to move line `let item = ...` inside the 'onclick' eventlistener for your code to work as the random color must be created each 'click'.

I made some changes to your original code showing how to use simple JS to modify a CSS *custom property* (`--color`) so you can use this value in CSS any way you like.

Additionally, I added a range slider to modify a second CSS *custom property* (`--base-hue`) with inline JS, controling the *hue* value of a CSS `hsl(..)` color.

Basically only CSS *custom properties* are modified with JS, none of the regular element style properties.

```js
let arr = [
    "black", "red", "silver", "gray",
    "white", "maroon", "red", "purple",
    "fuchsia", "green", "lime", "olive",
    "yellow", "navy", "blue", "teal", "aqua"
];

document.getElementById("btn").onclick = function (e) {
    let item = arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)];

    /* Change variable instead of 'background-color' */
    document.body.style.setProperty("--color", item);

    document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = item;
};
```

```css
html { height: 100%; width: 100% }

body {
     /* Modified by JS */
    --color: White; /* Initial values */
    --base-hue: 16;

    background-color: var(--color);
}

#btn {
    margin: auto;
    font-size: 50px; text-align: center;

    border: 3px solid green;
}

#name {
    margin: auto; margin-top: 7rem;
    font-size: 50px; text-align: center;

    /* set colors by using current hue value from range slider */
    background-color: hsl(var(--base-hue), 100%, 60%);  /* base hue */
    color: hsl(calc(var(--base-hue) + 180), 100%, 40%); /* +180 inverts */

    border: 3px solid green;
}

/* just eye candy */
.info {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; z-index: 9999;
    display: inline-flex; flex-direction: column;
    width: 100%; padding: 1rem; font-size: 1rem;
    background-color: hsl(0,0%,96%,.95); cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<label class="info">
    <span id="info-hue">Base Hue: 16</span>
    <input type="range" min="0" max="360" value="16" step="0.1"
           oninput="document.body.style.setProperty('--base-hue', this.value);
                    document.getElementById('info-hue').innerHTML = 'Base Hue: ' + this.value;">
</label>

<div id="name">Colour name will appear here</div>
<button id="btn" type="button">Click Me for colour change in background</button>
```